# Could not get unknown property 'appCompatVersion' for root project 'Socialize' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin-android-extensions

This is my dependencies `build.gradle:app`:

```
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$rootProject.appCompatVersion"

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$rootProject.coroutines"
api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$rootProject.coroutines"

// UI
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$rootProject.constraintLayoutVersion"
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$rootProject.materialVersion"

/* coroutines support for firebase operations */
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.1.1'


// Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:6.4.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

// Testing
testImplementation "junit:junit:$rootProject.junitVersion"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$rootProject.coreTestingVersion"
androidTestImplementation ("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$rootProject.espressoVersion", {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$rootProject.androidxJunitVersion"
```

This is android code of `build.gradle:app`:

```
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.socialize"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

I am trying to sync gradle project file and the error is:

```
Could not get unknown property 'appCompatVersion' for root project 'Socialize' of type 
org.gradle.api.Project.
Open File
```

When I click open file it prompt me back to first line dependencies file listed above

I added firebase to it and needed to add Kotlin coroutines files also.
I pasted this code from [here](https://github.com/Anuj-Kumar-Sharma/Social-App/blob/main/app/build.gradle) making [this](https://github.com/Anuj-Kumar-Sharma/Social-App) app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try solving this issue by adding this code to my `build.gradle`

```
ext {
appCompatVersion = '1.2.0'
constraintLayoutVersion = '2.0.2'
coreTestingVersion = '2.1.0'
coroutines = '1.3.9'
lifecycleVersion = '2.2.0'
materialVersion = '1.2.1'
// testing
junitVersion = '4.13.1'
espressoVersion = '3.1.0'
androidxJunitVersion = '1.1.2'
}
```

Basically this provide the version name to the implementation we have used in `build.gradle:app` where we have used `$rootProject.appCompatVersion`.

The `$rootProject` contains these variables with version defined in the above code.